# Error vs ProgramError mismatch (try_from_slice_checke )

Tags: anchor

Stuck on this mismatch error for this code.

```
fn try_deserialize(buf: &mut &[u8]) -> Result<Self, ProgramError> {
        try_from_slice_checked(buf, MetaplexKey::MetadataV1, MAX_METADATA_LEN).map(MetadataAccount)
    }
```

I keep getting this error, even if I change ProgramError to the Error.

```
expected enum anchor_lang::error::Error, found enum anchor_lang::prelude::ProgramError
```

So if I change it to `Result<Self, Error>`, I get the error from the `try_from_slice_checked` saying it is returning ProgramError.

If I keep it as `Result<Self, ProgramError>`, then it says it was expecting Error as the Result type.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here!

Comment: Does changing to `std::result::Result` solve the problem?

Comment: @vicyyn no haha I've gone as far as removing RUST and Anchor completely, and re-installing everything fresh.

Comment: please provide the full compiler output rather than cherry picking a single line